# Account Related Contacts in same Custom table in LWC in accordian manner

Tags: lightning-web-components, account, contact, table, accordion

I have designed an Account and its Contacts relationship in lightning Collapsible and Accordion style where data should should be in same table columns. The data is not populating correctly since it is under iteration, everytime it is showing contacts which are related to one account to all accounts and all fields are populationg while i like to show  data on which account button is clicked.

I am new to LWC , will appreciate any help

this picture shows the collapsed table showing all Accounts
[image]

while this picture shows expanded accounts with related contact[image]

here is JS Controller code

```javascript
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import  getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/getRecordDataController.getAccounts";
import getContacts from "@salesforce/apex/getRecordDataController.getContacts";

export default class AccountRelatedContact extends LightningElement {
    acclist; conList;accConList; 
    showRelatedContacts=false;accId;filteredConList;selectedAccId;accountId;

    @wire(getContacts) wiredContacts({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            //  console.log("conList ", data);
            this.conList = data;
            //  console.log("conList ", this.conList);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } 
    }
  
    @wire(getAccounts) wiredAccounts({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {        
            this.acclist = data;
            //  console.log("accList ", this.acclist);        
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    handleClick(event){
        // alert("button is clicked");
        let selectedAccId = event.target.name;   
        this.accountId=selectedAccId;
        let selectedAccLocalId = event.target.Id;             
        this.showRelatedContacts=!this.showRelatedContacts;
        this.filteredConList = this.conList.filter(function(currentItem,Index,array){
            if(currentItem.AccountId==selectedAccId){
                return currentItem;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HTML Template

```html
<template>
  <lightning-card>
    <div>
      <template if:true={acclist}>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
          <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="ICON">
                <lightning-button
                  icon-name="utility:bug"
                  class="button__icon_small slds-button"
                ></lightning-button>
              </div>
            </th> 
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Phone</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Email</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Kid</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
            <template for:each={acclist} for:item="item" for:index="index">
              <tr key={item.Id}>
                <th>
                  <!-- {index}   -->
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="ICON">
                    <lightning-button
                      
                      name={item.Id}
                      icon-name="utility:right"
                      class="button__icon_small slds-button"
                      onclick={handleClick}
                    ></lightning-button>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <td>{item.Name}</td>
                <td>{item.Phone}</td>
                <td>""</td>
              </tr>

              <template if:true={showRelatedContacts}>
                <template if:true={filteredConList}>
                  <template
                    for:each={filteredConList}
                    for:item="itemCon"
                    for:index="con"
                  >
                    <tr key={itemCon.Id}>
                      <td>{con}</td>
                      <td>{itemCon.Name}</td>
                      <td>{itemCon.Phone}</td>
                      <td>{itemCon.Email}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </template>
                </template>
              </template>
            </template>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </template>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provides an inbuilt LWC component for this i.e **Tree Grid**

*Reference link :* [Tree Grid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example)

- We need to fetch Accounts along with contacts by the inner query
- Then add contacts as **_children** as below screenshot
  [image]

*upvote or accept it, if it's helpful.*

Comment: Hi Naveen Thanks For the answer, but i also want to include inline editing in my component which is not supported in Tree Grid.